# Number Recognition on 7 segment using python ( for Rasberry Pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I am writing a code on Google Colaboratory using python to recognize the number on the device with 7segment(FND)

Part of the process of driving the motor with the Raspberry Pi 4.
I'm going to use the Python code to recognize the number of pictures taken from the camera in real time and send signals to the motor, which is the code for the camera to recognize the number of seven segments of the scale.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDlb0.jpg)

If i put all the code in, they say there are too many code contents, so I'll replace it with a capture screen in the beginning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH5IG.jpg)

```
image=cv2.imread("/content/cas.jpg")
image=imutils.resize(image, height=500)

gray=cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5),0)
edged = cv2. Canny (blurred,50,200,255)

contours=cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = grab_contours(contours)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
displayCnt = None

for c in contours :
  peri = cv2.arcLength(c,True)
  approx = cv2. approxPolyDP(c, 0.02*peri, True)
  if len(approx)==4 :
    displayCnt = approx
    break

[x, y,w, h] = cv2. boundingRect (displayCnt)
cv2. rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
plt. imshow(image)
plt. show ()

warped = four_point_transform(gray, displayCnt. reshape(4,2))
output=four_point_transform(image,displayCnt. reshape(4,2))
plt.imshow(warped)
plt.show()

thresh = cv2.threshold(warped, 0, 255,
                       cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement (cv2. MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1,5))
thresh = cv2. morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.show()

cnts = cv2. findContours (thresh. copy (), cv2. RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours (cnts)
digitCnts = []

for c in cnts :
   (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect (c)
   if w >= 30 and h>=3:
      digitCnts.append(c)

for digit in digitCnts:
   [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(digit)
   cv2.rectangle(output,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
plt.title('digit')
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QiVc.png)

The above picture shows that the bounding box is not tilted one for each joint, but if the values of W and H are corrected, it will be taken for each joint. (I lost that calibration value now, so I found some codes.)

like this, The bounding box is held or not held properly for each joint of the number.

I found various ways to use OpenCV through googling and modified them little by little, but there is an error in that one number is not recognized as a whole in common when hitting the bounding box. (It seems to be a problem caused by the toxic break of the joint in the 7th segment.)

I'm trying not to use deep learning and machine learning as much as I can, do you have any other recommendations or should I use deep learning and machine learning for this level of problems?

How should I correct or correct it here

Comment: take a single row at y=30 and another one at y=80  And any big transition from clear to dark indicates that the segment is on. with this you can detect all vertical segments. Do the same for horizontal segments.

Comment: I found using tesseract ocr to be much more reliable in detecting digits than any 7 segment model. It gets more accurate with Smoothing which you're already doing and combined with the correct PSM flag.